# bash read builtin does not echo input if script is piped to less

Tags: bash, pipe

I stumbled upon this strange behavior of the bash builtin read.
I have a interactive script which has the potential of generating a large output. So naturally you append `| less` to it.
The script will still ask you for your input but it will not echo what you typed.

Here is a small sample.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type:"
read -r input

echo "Typed: ${input}"
```

`sample.sh | less`

I noticed that this is not a general issue with pipes (e.g. `|cat` works).

Any clue would be appreciated.

A **SOLUTION** which works for me:

```
#!/bin/bash

STTY_ORIG="$(stty -g)"  # save stty settings
stty echo  # enable echo

echo "Type:"
read -e -r input  # use readline (backspace will not work otherwise)

echo "Typed: ${input}"

stty "${STTY_ORIG}"  # restore stty settings
```

Comment: I found a workaround (solution?) to this problem. Because the behavior looked like the echoing is disabled I just tried `stty echo` in my script and it works as expected (well, backspace is not working). Not sure about any side effects for less...

Comment: Great, you should click "Answer to your Question" and Accept the response to close the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A SOLUTION which works for me and did not show an side effects.
Basically just tweak and restore the terminal settings...

```
#!/bin/bash

STTY_ORIG="$(stty -g)"  # save stty settings
stty echo  # enable echo

echo "Type:"
read -e -r input  # use readline (backspace will not work otherwise)

echo "Typed: ${input}"

stty "${STTY_ORIG}"  # restore stty settings
```

Answer (score -1):

It actualy works for me.

The same script

```
martus@makus-pc:/tmp/src$ dpkg -l | grep bash
ii  bash   4.4-5   amd64   GNU Bourne Again SHell

martus@makus-pc:/tmp/src$ uname -a
Linux makus-pc 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1 (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit: Does the script works without piping less? Less won't show anything typed untill you hit enter.

Comment: The point is that you type "something" and it is not echoed (same behavior as if you would use `read -s`. Apart from that you get the expected behavior.